# How to parse JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, json

```
{"data":[
         "",{"id":"1","nom":"hello","message":["",{"id":1,"nom":"dad"}]},
            {"id":"2","nom":"hi","message":["",{"id":"1","nom":"marie"},{"id":"2","nom":"bob"}]}
        ]
}
```

how can i extract data form it using iOS

Comment: Have a look at the `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Comment: googling or basic search on SO? What have you tried?

Comment: Google JSON and you'll find the [JSON specification page](http://www.json.org/).  At the bottom of the page are listed 23 different JSON parsers written in Java.  Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `NSJSONSerialization` .

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id allValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:&jsonError];

if(jsonError!=nil)
   NSLog(@"Json_Err: %@",jsonError);

NSArray *result = [(NSDictionary*)allValues objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the Json sdk for your project and place the below code like this...

```
NSStrig *jsonString = @"your json string";
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [jsonString JSONValue];
```

Comment: yes i know but the problem is how can i enter and extract values from this